# Typescript: How to use an existing function with no arguments as a (React) event handler?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

**NOTE:** I'm somewhat of a Typescript newbie, so the answer to this is probably fairly obvious.

Imagine a simple situation in React Javascript, using a MUI Button:

```
// Event handler to close a dialog with no "e" argument
const closeDialog = () => closeTheDialogForReal();

// Component for a (MUI) button to close the dialog
const DialogCloseButton = () => <Button onClick={closeDialog} />
```

In Typescript that code results in:

> Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.

That makes sense: `Button.onClick` isn't expecting just any function, it expects one with a certain signature (the signature of `MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>`).

What I'm unclear on is, what's the simplest/easiest way to tell Typescript "I don't care: you might be giving me an argument, but I don't need to use it in my handler function, and that's ok."

I would have thought I could do exactly that by using `as`:

```
const SomeComponent = () => <Button onClick={closeDialog as MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>} />
```

... but then I get:

> Property 'href' is missing in type '{ children: string; onClick: MouseEventHandler; variant: "outlined"; }' but required in type '{ href: string; }'.

I know I could solve this with a `//@ts-ignore`, but is there any other (preferably simple) way to tell Typescript that it's ok that my provided function takes less arguments than it expects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one it will solve it.

```
  const DialogCloseButton = () => (
      <Button onClick={() => closeDialog()} />
        Close Dialog
      </Button>
    );
```

Comment: Thanks.  While that does fix it, it requires changing the underlying Javascript: technically having the wrapper arrow function is 0.00000001% less efficient than not having it ;)  In practice I don't think it would ever matter, but out of curiosity, is there a purely-TS way to solve this?

Comment: I think you can handle it by using ts's type assertion. 
onClick={closeDialog as React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>}

Comment: See my original question: I tried that, but got a new/related error `Property 'href' is missing in type '{ children: string; onClick: MouseEventHandler; variant: "outlined"; }' but required in type '{ href: string; }'.`